# Material-ui Select component not update state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I made multiple select input with `Material-UI`. By default state have an array of two objects. I set this state as select value, so it should show default objects as selected.
But problem is, that this not working, even when I try to select others items select updates this state but I can't to deselect default values.
I placed my code on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-glade-ur1e6?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values you created are separate than the values in vesselsList. If you change your default state to this it works.

```js
const [desiredVesselType, setDesiredVesselType] = useState([
    vesselsList[3],
    vesselsList[4]
  ]);
```

Comment: This actually works, but this is strange. In your solution in default value array we have references to objects, in my solution I just use fetched data as default value, which is the same values, just array of objects. In `console.log()` I see save result. What the difference?

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. If you try vesselsList.indexOf(desiredVesselTypes[0]) you will see that it will always be -1. For example if you had two variables that had the value "x", their values would be equal but not the same. The only way I think you could get around this is adjusting your checked prop for the checkbox.